# How do I go about building a macro that automatically runs in Access through an auxiliary program?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The company I work for uses a really odd program that essentially adds a skin to Access.

In fact, it's so much like Access that if you open up the program and watch the connection with the Access db, you can see the .ldb pop up.

I built a macro that's supposed to automatically run when the database opens but when the program is opened, it acts as if the database DIDN'T open even though I can see the .ldb file appear.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. That's by design. You can open an access database without going thru the startup macros - if the program opens the database from VB or Excel - it could be used to run queries or pull data from tables. That opens the ldb file but it won't run startup macros or forms

Comment: Is there a way I can run the startup macros without opening up the db in Access?

Comment: From the existing program? Do you have source code - what language is it in?

Comment: No source code, unfortunately. From what we've been able to dig up, it looks like most of it is in VBA but that's all password protected.